# How can I create and deploy applications to an EC2 instance via the AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking to see if I can create an instance and deploy applications to athis instance dynamically via the API. I only want these instances to be created when my application needs them, or I request for them to be created.

I have two applications that I need to deploy to each created instance which require some set up and installation of dependencies prior to their launch. When I am finished with this application, I want to terminate the instance.

Am I able to do this? If so, could someone please point me to the right section of the documentation. I have searched on the documentation and found some information about creating images but I am unsure as to what exactly I will need to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using an Autoscaling Group, you can create a launch configuration that will launch you instances. Using CodeDeploy, you would link your deployment group to the auto-scaling group.

See [Integrating AWS CodeDeploy with Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html)

> AWS CodeDeploy supports Auto Scaling, an AWS service that can launch
>   Amazon EC2 instances automatically according to conditions you define.
>   These conditions can include limits exceeded in a specified time
>   interval for CPU utilization, disk reads or writes, or inbound or
>   outbound network traffic. Auto Scaling terminates the instances when
>   they are no longer needed. For more information, see What Is Auto
>   Scaling?.

Assuming you set your desired/minimum instances to 0, then the default state of the ASG will be to have no instances.

When you application needs an instance spun up, it would simply change the desired instance value to 1. When your application is completed with the instance, it would set your desired count to 0 again, thereby terminating that instance.

To develop this setup, start by running your instance normally (manually) and get the application deployment working.  When that works, then create your auto scaling group. Finally, update your deployment group to refer to the ASG so that your code is deployed when you have scaling events.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, this looks promising. I'm just going through this now and I'm on the launch configuration creation. Is it possible to create a launch configuration from my already configured instance or does it have to be a blank instance, then everything gets installed? Also, I don't really want auto scaling, I want scaling when I request for it to be scaled. Is this also possible with Autoscaling Groups? Ultimately I want complete control over instance creation/termination.

Comment: If you have an fully configured instance, then you would save the image as a custom AMI, and use that in your launch configuration.  Auto-scaling can really be automatic or manual, so your use case, where you control total instance life-cycle according to your application requirements is supported was well,

Comment: I have done all of this, probably not correct, but I have a scaling group, launch config and used a default Ubuntu AMI and the instance is launched correctly, but it has not run my commands in the instance that I specified in the launch config, and it hasn't deployed my code that I set up in CodeDeploy. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking for something like I request for another instance to be added, it launches the instance, installs all dependencies (that I provide in launch config), then deploys my applications to the instance. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can't even seem to deploy using CodeDeploy via the aws console. It spins and tries to install for a while and then fails on HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS, but the instance is healthy and running.

Comment: Yes - The setup is pretty standard for this usecase - ASG + CodeDeploy.  It works as above. If it is not, then you need check the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log and review. Do you see a CodeDeploy lifecyclehook in the ASG? Do you see the the deployment group trying to deploy?

Comment: I checked `cloud-init-output.log` and I only see this `2017-12-20 14:58:03,954 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'b'sudo -s'...'` and yes I see the CodeDeploy under lifecyclehook in the ASG. The deployment stays in "In Progress" before timing out or something. Instance never goes offline.

Comment: Looks like a dos2unix encoding issue perhaps? Keep troubleshooting it. You are on the correct path. PS You do not need `sudo` in userdata

Comment: I removed sudo and all of the other commands to replace it with something more simple, and even a simple `mkdir` won't work.. ` __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata:`. Same error, still looking around.

Comment: I can perform simple commands like `mkdir` now, but I can't seem to install anything using `apt-get`. Now in the cloud-init-output.log I get `2017-12-20 16:23:31,759 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [100]
2017-12-20 16:23:31,764 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2017-12-20 16:23:31,765 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
`

Comment: Lets have a look at /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 - can you post that?

Comment: I've got around this for now by just creating a custom AMI with all the dependencies which seems to work fine. However the code or applications are still not deployed to the new instances. Is there something I'm missing to get my actual applications on there?

Comment: Not sure - its a little hard to troubleshoot from comments.  But this solution does work. Can you reach out to AWS support?

Comment: As far as I am aware you have to pay extra for technical support; I thought SO might be able to help. This sort of seems outside the scope of the current question though so I will post a new one for more detailed help. It seems I will be able to scale the ASG and the CodeDeploy will do the rest, but that doesn't seem to work at the moment.